# How to call the id of selected multiple item option without using v-for in vue js?

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

I get dificulties passing the value of selected multiple option using vue js when I edit the post.
I use element ui for option selected.

PostController

```
return Post::with('category')->with('tag')->find($id);
```

Post.vue

```
 <el-select  v-model="form.tag_id" multiple placeholder="Select some">
    <el-option  v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag.id" :label="tag.name" 
    :value="tag.id">
   </el-option>
  </el-select>

<script>
data() {
return {
  tags: [],
  form: new Form({
    tag: [],
    tag_id: [],
  }),
}
// fetch all tags list
axios.get('/' + this.$route.params.trans + '/adminGetTags')
.then(({data}) => this.tags = data) 
//fetch post and tag which related to post
axios.get('/' + this.$route.params.trans + '/editPost/' + 
this.$route.params.id)
.then(({data}) => {
 //....
this.form.tag = data.tag
this.form.tag_id = data.tag
})

</script>
```

I need to call the id of selected multiple item like this

```
this.form.tag_id = data.tag.id
```

Buit it will give an error ( Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

But if I use v-for it will work, unfortunately I can't use v-model and v-for in select tag. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Result
[image: The result of that code]

[image: development]

Comment: have you tried `this.form.tag_id = [data.tag.id]` if I remember right vue will detect the `multiple` directive and set the expected type to an array

Comment: Justin, It's not working. Throw an error `[Vue warn]: <transition-group> children must be keyed: <ElTag> `. But if I change el-select to normal multiple select, it didn't give anything. There's no error, it's empty.

Comment: Inspect your data.tag.id. A working example for preselected options in element.io https://jsfiddle.net/deepaksingh/fpjaqcfn/

Comment: Deepak, thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. Actually, I need to know the implementation with database. And I can solve it now, just looping them in methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use looping for in script section, and it's working well for me.

```
       var j = 0;
       for(var i=1; i<= data.tag.length; i++)
       {

           this.form.tag_id[j] = data.tag[j].id
           j += 1 
       }
       return this.form.tag_id
```